# How can you cache gradle inside docker?

Tags: docker, gradle

I'm trying to cache things that my gradle build download each time currently. For that I try to mount a volume with the -v option like `-v gradle_cache:/root/.gradle`

The thing is each time I rerun the build with the exat same command it still downloads everything again. The full command I use to run the image is

```
sudo docker run --rm -v gradle_cache:/root/.gradle -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle:jdk8-alpine gradle jar
```

I also checked in the directory where docker saves the volumes content at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/gradle_cache/_data` but that is also empty.

[my console log](https://gist.github.com/usbpc/a8ded82329470bc711869525f56e47a8)

What am I missing to make this working?

Edit: As per request I rerun the command with the [`--scan`](https://scans.gradle.com/s/flfozrtpdalmw/) option.

And also with a diffrent gradle home:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -v gradle_cache:/root/.gradle -v "$PWD":/home/gradle/project -w /home/gradle/project gradle:jdk8-alpine gradle jar --gradle-user-home /root/.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to load native library 'libnative-platform.so' for Linux amd64.
```

Comment: What happens if you run the command like `gradle jar --gradle-user-home /root/.gradle`? Also, if you have a newer Gradle version can you run with `--scan` and add the link to the question?

Comment: Updated the question with the information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/b0419babd3271f6c8e554fbc8bbd8dc909936763/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile) for the Container I'm using I found out, that the right option to use is `-v gradle_cache:/home/gradle/.gradle`.

What made me think that the files were cached in `/root/.gradle` is that the Dockerfile also sets that up as a symlink from `/home/gradle/.gradle`:

[`ln -s /home/gradle/.gradle /root/.gradle`](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/b0419babd3271f6c8e554fbc8bbd8dc909936763/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile#L38)

So inspecting the filesystem after a build made it look like the files were stored there.

Answer (score 3):

Since 6.2.1, Gradle now supports a shared, read-only dependency cache for this scenario:

> It’s a common practice to run builds in ephemeral containers. A container is typically spawned to only execute a single build before it is destroyed. This can become a practical problem when a build depends on a lot of dependencies which each container has to re-download. To help with this scenario, Gradle provides a couple of options:
>
> - copying the dependency cache into each container
> - sharing a read-only dependency cache between multiple containers

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html#sub:ephemeral-ci-cache describes the steps to create and use the shared cache.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to have more control on the cache directory you can use this:

```
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME /path/to/custom/cache/dir
VOLUME $GRADLE_USER_HOME
```